# Understanding Partition density of partitioned network

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

i am implementing Link Communities community detection algorithm. I have trouble understanding explanation of partition density described in the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3178.pdf)

Here is only the part defining partition density:
[image]

I cannot find the connection between definition of link density (equation 2) and definition of partition density (equation 3). Because of that, i dont understand why is partition density defined the way it is. And i especially dont see how is (equation 3) calculating average of (equation 2) - if there is average, i would expect number of partitions (c) to be below horizontal line (in the divisor)

I could not google any other definition of partition density.

Anyone who can shed some light into it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an average, but rather a weighted sum: each community is weighted depending on the proportion of total links it contains (i.e. mc). So instead of having a uniform factor of 1/C, where C is the number of communities, you have a community-specific factor of mc/M.

Answer (score 0):

(2) is the density of one community, (3) is the weighted density sum of all communities, the weight is $m_c / M$.